# Multiple Plug-ins Contribute Same Command

Tags: java, eclipse

I have multiple independent plug-ins that should contribute a command to an application's toolbar. Since there is an ID field in the command part I would have assumed that having something like that in all plug-ins would only display the command once:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
        <toolbar id="org.acme.plugin.toolbar">
            <command
                    commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.print"
                    id="main.print"
                    style="push">
            </command>
        </toolbar>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Needless to say, the command is displayed multiple times. I tried adding it directly to add it to the toolbar (which does not work in my use-case anyway, since the plug-ins are independent), hoping to trigger the "identifiable" part of the command, but still the command gets displayed multiple times:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="toolbar:org.acme.plugin.toolbar">
        <command
                commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.print"
                id="main.print"
                style="push">
        </command>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Surely it can't be too exotic for someone to have the requirement "display command if any of a list of plug-ins is present" - so how do I do that?

Comment: How about an additional common plugin with the toolbar items.

Comment: @greg-449 Creating a entire plug-in for a single command sounds like overkill, and adding a layer in the dependency hierarchy only for it seems like a bad idea.